# Convert a categorical valued column to its statistical values in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-processing

I have a dataframe whose sample is given below.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'ID':['A','B','C','D','E','F'],
'Gender':['Man', 'Woman', 'Transgender', 'Non-binary,Transgender', 'Woman,Non-binary', 
'Man,Non-binary,Transgender']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

[image]

Now, I want to create a column for each value in the 'Gender' column and if the value is present in the row, the new column should have '1' else empty. The final form required is shown below.

[image]

Cannot use pd.get_dummies() as there are multiple values(ex: 'Non-binary, Transgender') in many rows.
I thought of manually hardcoding for all values, but wanted to know if there is a way to automate the process.
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you can split on `,` to easily come back to a situation where you can use `get_dummies`:

```
>>> df_split = df[['ID']].join(df['Gender'].str.split(',')).explode('Gender')
>>> df_split
  ID       Gender
0  A          Man
1  B        Woman
2  C  Transgender
3  D   Non-binary
3  D  Transgender
4  E        Woman
4  E   Non-binary
5  F          Man
5  F   Non-binary
5  F  Transgender
>>> dummies = pd.get_dummies(df_split['Gender']).groupby(df_split['ID']).max().reset_index()
>>> dummies
  ID  Man  Non-binary  Transgender  Woman
0  A    1           0            0      0
1  B    0           0            0      1
2  C    0           0            1      0
3  D    0           1            1      0
4  E    0           1            0      1
5  F    1           1            1      0 
>>> df.merge(dummies, on='ID')
  ID                      Gender  Man  Non-binary  Transgender  Woman
0  A                         Man    1           0            0      0
1  B                       Woman    0           0            0      1
2  C                 Transgender    0           0            1      0
3  D      Non-binary,Transgender    0           1            1      0
4  E            Woman,Non-binary    0           1            0      1
5  F  Man,Non-binary,Transgender    1           1            1      0
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `Series.str.get_dummies`, which allows you to specify a separator in the case of multiple values in a string, then join the result back.

```
pd.concat([df, df['Gender'].str.get_dummies(',').add_prefix('Gender_')], axis=1)

  ID                      Gender  Gender_Man  Gender_Non-binary  Gender_Transgender  Gender_Woman
0  A                         Man           1                  0                   0             0
1  B                       Woman           0                  0                   0             1
2  C                 Transgender           0                  0                   1             0
3  D      Non-binary,Transgender           0                  1                   1             0
4  E            Woman,Non-binary           0                  1                   0             1
5  F  Man,Non-binary,Transgender           1                  1                   1             0
```

Comment: Any way to replace these 0 with an empty string('')?

Comment: @Shiva you can use `replace` on the dummies DataFrame. Just change it to `df['Gender'].str.get_dummies(',').add_prefix('Gender_').replace(0, '')`